# Apache Airflow ignore failed task

Tags: airflow

Is there a way to ignore failed task and proceed to next step after let's say 2 re-tries?

Example;

```
t1= SomeOperator(...)
t2= SomeOperator(...)

t2.set_upstream(t1)


# if t1 fails re-try 2 times and proceed to t2

# else if t1 success then proceed to t2 as usual
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take a look at airflows [trigger rules](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules).

By default, the trigger rule for every task is `'all_success'`, meaning the task will only get executed when all directly upstream tasks have succeeded.

What you would want here is the trigger rule `'all_done'`, meaning all directly upstream tasks are finished, no matter whether they failed or succeeded.

But be careful, as this also means that if a task that is not directly upstream fails, and the tasks following that task get marked as `'upstream_failed'`, the task with this trigger rule will still get executed.

So in your case, you would have to set `retries=2` for t1 and `trigger_rule='all_done'` for t2.